# raspberry piとwindows7でbluetooth接続

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth

タイトルの通りraspberry pi(version1 B)とwindows7をbluetooth接続して，
シリアル通信をおこなっていきたいと考えています．
サイトはこちらを参考にしています．
http://totech.hateblo.jp/entry/2017/01/09/121706
http://totech.hateblo.jp/entry/2017/03/15/093608

ですが，

```
$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]power on
[bluetooth]scan on
[bluetooth]pair (windowsのアドレス)
[bluetooth]connect (windowsのアドレス)
```

としてもすぐに

```
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

と接続が破棄されてしまいます．
たまに接続が確立されても数分後には同じ結末になります．

解決策としてサイトを検索し

```
[bluetooth]agent DisplayYesNo
```

を行ったり，

```
[bluetooth]remove (windowsのアドレス)
```

を行い初期化したり，

```
$ sudo reboot
```

で再起動したりは試みました．
他に手立てがあればぜひ教えていただきたいです．

Comment: かなり前のことなのでうろ覚えなのですが`bluez-simple-agent`を使い`bluez-simple-agent -c NoInputNoOutput hci0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` とすると似た状況で接続を確立できました。当時英語版のstackoverflowに質問したのがこちらです。 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273935/cant-pairing-with-bluetooth-speaker-by-using-bluez-simple-agent 全く無関係かもしれませんがもしかしたらと思いコメントいたしました。

Comment: ありがとうございます．最新のbluezには`bluez-simple-agent`は入っていないので(対話型のbluetoothctlのみ)，versionをダウングレードすることも検討してみます．